# ksoap2 stringArray for php Request

Tags: php, soap, ksoap2

How to make such a request?

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:CurrencySyncDelete>
        <Row xsi:type="ns2:Map">
            <item>
                <key xsi:type="xsd:string">ID</key>
                <value xsi:type="xsd:int">999</value>
            </item>
        </Row>
    </ns1:CurrencySyncDelete>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Comment: You write code...

Answer (score 0):

I decided the problem with the help of marshaling 
http://read.pudn.com/downloads143/sourcecode/mobile/j2me/625948/branches/2_1_0_AttributePatch_1473145/ksoap2/ksoap2/src/org/ksoap2/serialization/MarshalHashtable.java__.htm